# How to configure a Cosmos Db collection during deployment

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cosmosdb

When deploying a Cosmos Db database in GlobalDocumentDB mode using the Azure [resource manager template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.documentdb/databaseaccounts) there is no way to configure collections in the database during deployment that I can tell.

During a ARM template deployment is there any way to either (in order of preference)

1. Configure the collections in a Cosmos Db database directly in a way that I have overlooked.
2. Do a series of REST requests from within the template to configure the db.
3. Do a single REST request within the template to hit a Azure Function with a HttpTrigger that will configure the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use these Templates.

- Containers: 
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.documentdb/2015-04-08/databaseaccounts/apis/databases/containers
- Collections: 
   
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.documentdb/2015-04-08/databaseaccounts/apis/databases/collections
- All Microsoft.DocumentDB Resource Types: 
   
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.documentdb/allversions

These pages were published on `05/01/2019` & are for API version `2015-04-08`.

Answer (score 0):

ARM templates is used to create Azure resources, there is no way to configure collection during deploy ARM template. To configure collections, I suggest you use REST API. Before creating a collection, we need to create a database first. Following are documents which show us how to create DocumentDB databases and collections.

[Create Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/create-a-database)

[Create Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/create-a-collection)