# How to properly provision database and collection in deployment pipeline?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-resource-manager

Bit longer question ahead but please bear with me: A CosmosDB PM explains in [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/13427997-create-db-collections-using-arm-template) feedback thread:

> In Cosmos DB, all of the resources e.g. databases, collections/tables/graphs, users, permissions, documents/items/nodes/edges, attachments are all runtime resources. You can CRUD/query these resources using runtime SDKs and REST APIs. [...] All of the “runtime resources” [...] are meant to be used by the developers directly inside their applications.
>
> The only resource which is meant for administrative purposes is the “database account”. This resource is exposed via ARM.

So only the resource "CosmosDB" can be provisioned using ARM (Azure Resource Manager), e.g. in a CI/CD pipeline for instance with Azure DevOps.

So now my question is: **What is the proper way to create the Database(s) and Collection(s) inside a CosmosDB account?**

Let's say I am using am using an Azure Function that stores/reads data from a CosmosDB. Using the Function Binding I could for example use

`[DocumentDB("ToDoList", "Migration", ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDB", CreateIfNotExists = true)] IAsyncCollector<Document> documentsToStore)`

to create db and collection. Instantiating the DocumentClient manually I could use
`await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(database);`

But: Is this the proper way to do this?? Doing it for instance in the Function binding would mean that the collection wouldn't be created until the Function is executed for the first time. That just does not feel right.

Or should one instead use for instance a Powershell script in the deployment pipeline to create db and collection after the ARM script was deployed? This is of course doable but if that would be the recommended way, one can very much argue that this should be exposed through ARM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure a Cosmos Db collection during deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223053/how-to-configure-a-cosmos-db-collection-during-deployment)

Comment: I answered this on another question which gets at the same question: ### How to deploy the container/collection with infrastructure & without having to run optional bootstrapping code during startup? <br/>
ARM Templates now exist to provision these. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55962822/237723

Answer (score -1):

The answer to this question is entirely dependent on the intent of the function you are trying to build I feel. If the function assumes it can read/update/delete documents in a collection that might or might not exist then yes it a good practice to challenge the collection and then create it on the fly if it does not exist yet.

If the collection needs to be created because other tools depend on it and it is a predictable collection you can create them beforehand but if the collections name or number cannot be predicted then you are in a bind.

Comment: I wouldn’t really agree. First, the Function was just an example. Could be any app that uses CosmosDB. Second, it just doesn’t feel like a good idea to provision Db and collection at runtime. If somebody can give a proper explanation for that, I’d be very happy.